# What is the return type of DgsDataFetchingEnvironment.getSelectionSet?

Tags: java, graphql

I am working with the the lib "com.netflix.graphql.dgs.DgsDataFetchingEnvironment".
When writing the unit test, I need to mock dfe.getSelectionSet(). So I need to know the return type of dfe.getSelectionSet().
My IntelliJ IDE can't work with this lib well, I have to query the function by javadoc.
However, after search the internet, I can't find its API doc.
If its API doc is absent, is there any way I can know the return type of this function?
[image: DgsDataFetchingEnvironment not resolved]

1, viewed the doc https://netflix.github.io/dgs/getting-started/, https://github.com/netflix/dgs-framework. Not able to find any API doc
2, try to configure the IDE, but not succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrapper around standard `graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment`

The `DgsDataFetchingEnvironment` gives access to the context, the query itself, data loaders, and the source object.

[docs can be found here](https://netflix.github.io/dgs/datafetching/)

[source code can be found here](https://github.com/Netflix/dgs-framework/blob/master/graphql-dgs/src/main/kotlin/com/netflix/graphql/dgs/DgsDataFetchingEnvironment.kt)